# Vue axios's Get response in another file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, axios

I am trying to return the results of Service.js by evoking it in Report.js, but I keep getting **"[object Promise]"** error.

Can someone please point the mistake?

Service.js (where I will have all the API calls)

```
function getReport() {

     return axios
        .get("https://xxx/api/report", {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${this.$store.getters.getAuthToken}` },
        })
        .then(response => {
            return response.data
        });
}
```

Report.js

```
data() {
    return {
      responseTest: "",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getCurrentRespone();
  },
  methods: {
     async getCurrentRespone(){
     await service.getReport().then(response => this.responseTest = response.data);
     return this.responseTest;

      }

  },
```

Comment: In getReport()'s promise you return response.data. In getCurrentResponse you treat it like it's still a response object and not the data itself. So you shouldn't need to use .data again

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really get it. Can you pass me the structure of both functions?

Comment: `getCurrentRespone()` returns promise. You cannot use it directly to print in view like `{{getCurrentResponse()}}`. it will print Promise as shown above. You should instead print `{{this.responseTest }}`. Also, don't mix await and chaning using `then`. Search how to convert `then..catch` to `await` syntax properly.